# App/provider circular dependency

Tags: angularjs, provider

I want to use a provider to set some configuration settings at starting up my AngularJs app, but I would like to have the app and the provider in 2 seperate files.

This is how I have it now:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.config(function(myServiceProvider) {
....etc.
```

The provider is defined like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').provider('myService', function () {
...etc.
```

If I load the app first the provider is not there yet, and if I load the provider first the app is not there yet.
What would be the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your module definition includes *module* dependencies - not services or providers.

It should be:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

The config block is always executed after your providers are initialized.  There is no circular dependency issue.

File 1: Define module

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
```

File 2: Define providers

```
angular.module('myApp').provider('myService',function() {...});
```

File 3: Define config block

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function(myServiceProvider) { ... });
```

HTML:

```
<script src="/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/file1.js"></script>
<script src="/file2.js"></script>
<script src="/file3.js"></script>
```

Order of the files is important.

Comment: my bad, but removing that still gives the same problem, probably from when myApp.config is requiring it to be injected

Comment: Your module definition must have an empty module array as a dependency. Otherwise, you are trying to retrieve a module that has not been defined yet.

Comment: yeah sorry, but still the same problem then.

Comment: Ah, I think I know what the issue is. You can't have the module definition and the config method call in the same file. The provider hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: that's the problem then indeed, was hoping I could work around that somehow but I guess I have to move the config to a seperate file then to get the load order right

Comment: @Maarten: **Note**: Things have changed in Angular verison `1.3.0-beta.8` and later. From that version onwards, `.config()` blocks are executed after loading services etc, so the order of appearance does not play a role. See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zylZabr96BX76bS8FoEq?p=preview)**.

Answer (score 1):

in your first file:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.config(function(myServiceProvider) {
....etc.
```

and in your second file:

```
myApp.provider('myService', function () {
...etc.
```

The variable myApp is a global variable and you can access to this everywhere in your website.
You can take a look at the [Yeoman project](http://yeoman.io/), it's a generator which create your angularjs app structure and add lot of cool features.

Comment: that is just a different syntax for adding the provider to the app, but it doesn't solve my problem